Where am I wrong calculating this noise figure for this circuit?
The following is a question given my teacher.

Determine the noise figure of the stages below with respect to a
source impedance of \$_\$. Neglect  body effect, but not
channel-length modulation. Assume the current sources \$I_1\$, \$I_2\$
are noiseless.



$$\frac{V_{in} - V_x} {R_S} = \frac{V_x} {r_{o2}} + V_{out} g_{m2}$$
$$V_x g_{m1} + \frac{V_{out}} {r_{o1}} = 0$$
$$\Rightarrow A_v = \frac{V_{out}} {V_{in}} = \frac{g_{m1} r_{o1} r_{o2}} {g_{m1} g_{m2} r_{o1} r_{o2} R_S - r_{o2} - R_S}$$
The noise voltage (\$\frac{4 K T \gamma} {g_{m2}})\$ which is induced by M2.

$$\overline{V_{n,M2}^2} = \frac{4 K T \gamma} {g_{m2}}$$
The noise current (\$4 K T \gamma g_{m1})\$ which is induced by M1.

$$\overline{V_{n,M1}^2} = 4 K T \gamma g_{m1} r_{o1}^2$$
$$NF = 1 + \frac{1} {4 K T R_S}  \frac{\overline{V_{n,M1}^2} + \overline{V_{n,M2}^2}} {A_v^2}$$
Substitute those values we have calculated earlier respectively.
$$NF = 1 + \frac{1} {4 K T R_S}  \frac{ 4 K T \gamma g_{m1} r_{o1}^2 + \frac{4 K T \gamma} {g_{m2}} } {\frac{g_{m1} r_{o1} r_{o2}} {g_{m1} g_{m2} r_{o1} r_{o2} R_S - r_{o2} - R_S}}$$
$$\Rightarrow NF = 1 + \frac{1} {R_S}  \frac{  \gamma g_{m1} r_{o1}^2 + \frac{ \gamma} {g_{m2}} } {\frac{g_{m1} r_{o1} r_{o2}} {g_{m1} g_{m2} r_{o1} r_{o2} R_S - r_{o2} - R_S}}$$
However, they said isn't correct. but he doesn't tell me where I am wrong.

@MarcusMüller Take a look at what I have tried.

@MarcusMüller Can you thumbs up my problem instead of thumbs down?

I didn't downvote your question, and I must admit you solving the issue of not showing any own attempt isn't really what makes a good (upvote-worthy) question. For example, you still don't actually ask a question to help you get ahead. There's no attempt to combine the formula for noise figure (whichever formula you might be using!) with your intermediate results. So, no, sorry, can't upvote.

@MarcusMüller How about now?

Where did you address "you still don't actually ask a question to help you get ahead."?

Also, where's the minimum diligence that you'd apply to such a formula, such as cancelling all common terms, and avoiding fractions in under fractions if possible?

In this answer, I am going to assume \$g_mr_o \gg 1\$ which typically holds for amplifier circuits with MOSFETs in the saturation region. Your mistake is in calculating the output resistance, which gets multiplied by \$4kT\gamma g_{m_1}\$ to determine the contribution of \$M_1\$. Let's apply a test voltage \$V_t\$ at the output and calculate \$r_{\text{out}}\overset{\Delta}{=}\frac{V_t}{I_t}\$:
$$I_t = \frac{V_t}{r_{o_1}} - g_{m_1}g_{m_2}R_S\Vert r_{o_2}V_t$$ which yields:
$$r_{\text{out}} = r_{o_1} \Vert \frac{-1}{g_{m_1}g_{m_2}R_S\Vert r_{o_2}} \approx r_{o_1} \Vert \frac{-1}{g_{m_1}g_{m_2}R_S}.$$ This is because for most circuits \$r_o \gg R_S\$. By the way, the second term is indeed negative because of positive feedback! Furthermore, typically, this will simplify to:
$$r_{\text{out}} \approx \frac{-1}{g_{m_1}g_{m_2}R_S}.$$
Now we can write:
$$\overline{V^2_{n,M_1}} = 4kT\gamma g_{m_1} r_{\text{out}}^2 = 4kT\gamma g_{m_1} \cdot \frac{1}{g^2_{m_1}g^2_{m_2}R^2_S} = \frac{4kT\gamma}{g_{m_1}g^2_{m_2}R^2_S}.$$
Now, let's simplify your gain equation for \$g_mr_o\gg1\$ which is typically the case in a well-designed amplifier:
$$A_v \approx \frac{1}{g_{m_2}R_S}.$$
As a sanity check, note that this is essentially the inverse of your feedback ratio, which makes sense for a feedback amplifier with large loop gain. Now we are equipped to find the noise figure:
$$NF \approx 1 + \frac{1}{4kTR_S}\cdot\frac{\frac{4kT\gamma}{g_{m_1}g^2_{m_2}R^2_S} + \frac{4kT\gamma}{g_{m_2}}}{A^2_v} = 1+\gamma\frac{\frac{1}{g_{m_1}g^2_{m_2}R^2_S} + \frac{1}{g_{m_2}}}{\frac{1}{g_{m_2}^2 R_S}}=1+\frac{\gamma}{g_{m_1}R_S}+g_{m_2}R_S\gamma.$$

I don't understands how you calculate this output impedance. Do you have to break the loop? Can you draw some schematics diagram if you have time?

Here is what I thought of output resistance.
https://i.imgur.com/ObBIOmp.jpeg
$$R_{out} = (g_{m1} r_{o1} +1) \parallel \infty$$
$$\Rightarrow R_{out}=\ (g_{m1} r_{o1} +1) $$

@kile the analysis in your figure is wrong. You are not accounting for the current caused by $M_2$. Your test voltage source induces a current in $M_2$ and hence, in $M_1$. This term is then in parallel with $r_{o_1}$. If you want to use the feedback theory, the open-loop value is $r_{o_1}$ and the loop gain is $-g_{m_2}R_{S}g_{m_1}r_{o_1}$. Thus, $r_{out} \approx r_{o_1} / (1 - g_{m_2}R_{S}g_{m_1}r_{o_1}) \approx -1 / g_{m_1}g_{m_2}R_{S}$.

Where do you break the loop? Can you draw the schematics to illustrate your idea?

Suppose you break the  loop at the gate of M1, loop gain will be $$LG = g_{m1} g_{m2} r_{o1} (r_{o2} \parallel R_S)$$

@kile that is absolutely correct. The only assumption I made here is that $R_S \ll r_{o_2}$. While that is true in most cases, you do not have to make that assumption. Longer algebra, but similar results.
